# How to call mongodb server function inside update statement

Tags: php-mongodb

Lets say there is an array defined as sub document.

```
User
 first_name:"blah",
 last_name: "blah",
 scores [{score: 12},
         {score: 13},
         {score: 9},
         {score: 14}]
```

Say I want to loop through this sub array inside the update statement and check if I need to add a new score. New score could be 8 or 16 if its 8 then nothing should be added, however if its 16 it should be added to the end of the list.
Is there is anyway to define javascript server side function and use it inside update statement, or there are other way of doing something like that? The important thing that operation has to be atomic.

Using php driver

```
public bool|array MongoCollection::update ( array $criteria , array $new_object [, array $options = array() ] )
```

How do I specify criteria to match those conditions that I have listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a server-side javascript function, however the creators of mongo [do not recommend this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/):

> We do not recommend using server-side stored functions if possible.

If you need atomicity with complex logic, one approach with is to lock the document before working with it. You can achieve this with the [`findAndModify` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). The basic gist of this is that you try to `find` your document as you normally would, with the additional criteria that `locked = false`. The modify part of this function would set `locked = true`.

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { name: "Andy", locked: false },
    update: { locked: true },
});
```

You now are free to work with the document "atomically" When you write the changes back to your database, you set `locked = false`. Make sure you wrap your block in a `try/catch/finally` and ensure the document is unlocked in the `finally` block.

Note that if your operation is very simple (simply need to add a field to your list), then using `findAndModify` alone to update the document fields may be enough for what you need.

**Edit:** If you really want to use server-side functions here's an example from the [PHP mongo documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mongodb.execute.php):

```
$response = $db->execute("function(x) { return x;}", array("input param"));
```

Here's how you could persist a function for later use (through the mongo shell)

```
db.system.js.save(
               { _id: "echoFunction",
                 value : function(x) { return x; }
               }
             )
```

Then later in PHP:

```
$response = $db->execute("echoFunction( 'test' )");
var_dump($response);
```

**Edit2**:
Your update function is much easier than I first understood. You simply need the following:

```
$db->update(
    array("first_name" => "blah"), 
    array(
        "$push" => array(
            "scores" => array("score" => 16)
        )
    )
);
```

Edit2: Access your collection from inside a function

```
function push_score(id, score) {
  //your logic here
  //...
  db.your_collection.update({_id: ObjectId(id), $push: {scores: {score: score}}})
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your answer however with locking I understand that I can implement my own mechanism if I have too, what I dont understand is how I can use server side function within update statement. If you could share some code snippet that does that I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes I understand this better now thanks Martin, so this example from php help page does not really show how to use server side logic in particular how would you pass sub array in that function and modify document I just cant find a good example anywhere.

Comment: I see - I updated my post again..it was much simpler after I read your question again :/. You only call the update when you know score = 16. This operation is atomic.

Comment: All this statement does is pushes new item to the end of the array it does not check what is the current highest also if I change 16 to 8 it will not work. So the logic inside stored function should be something like this: 1. loop though all the items 2. find highest see if newval > then highest if so insert. And all of this logic has to be atomic.

Comment: Ok I must have misunderstood your question. Regardless you have all the tools necessary now - you simply need to write a JS function that will manipulate your array according to your rules. Save this function as I posted, and then call this JS function from PHP. The function will lock the document while it's running and therefore be atomic. Best of luck!

Comment: Added some sample code so you can see how to call update from within a function

Comment: As of MongoDB 4.2 `eval` in mongodb and correspondingly `execute` in PHP are deprecated... How would you call a user-defined function in mongodb via PHP?